# Custom Annotation like Butterknifes "@OnClick" for android viewBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I migrated a project from butterknife to android viewBinding.

In Butterknife there is something like:

```
@OnClick(R.id.button)
fun onButtonClicked()
```

And now I have to set all the button click listener like this:

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener { onButtonClicked() }
...
```

Is there a way to implement a custom annotation to be able to write something like:

```
@OnClick(binding.button)
fun onButtonClicked()
```

Answer (score 2):

> And now I have to set all the button click listener like this:

Yes, This is the right way of doing click listeners with View Binding.

> Is there a way to implement a custom annotation to be able to write something like:

No. There isn't any out of the box solutions available for it. but you can create your own annotation processor for handling click listeners. Follow [this article](https://medium.com/androidiots/writing-your-own-annotation-processors-in-android-1fa0cd96ef11) for more info.

If you ask for my personal opinion I will follow the default way and use `setOnClickListener`. Jake Wharton, the creator of `Butterknife` suggests using View Binding (He is also part of the team at Google which is working on View Binding)

Comment: It's just... it feels like a step backwards. Annotations are so "comfortable"